Clone/Fork a Process in C++ on Windows?
I'm attempting to understand what is the proper way to clone/fork a process in C++ on Windows. All the examples below are compiled & ran using Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 system.
It is my understanding that the classic fork function is only available on Unix systems, through the unistd.h header. I'm looking for something that can replicate fork's behaviour on Windows.

I understand that the Windows API has the CreateProcessW and CreateProcessA functions, that can create a child process with a given Command Prompt string, as illustrated by the following minimal example that just runs another executable file test.exe:
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <Windows.h>

bool RunChildProcess(std::string command)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> stringConverter;
    bool result = CreateProcess(NULL, stringConverter.from_bytes(command.c_str()).data(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (result)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string command = "test.exe";
    bool runResult = RunChildProcess(command);

    if (!runResult)
    {
        std::cout << "\n-- ERROR: Failed to run child command \"" + command + "\"! --\n";
        return 1;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

However, what I'm looking for here is being able to clone a process and have the created child process(es) start executing within the function I cloned it in, right after the call to the cloning function, which is not what these CreateProcess functions do. They instead always create processes with other executable files.

I also found this rewrite of the fork() function for Windows, which uses the RtlCloneUserProcess function from ntdll.dll to clone a process. However, I am having difficulties using it to perform a process clone.
Attempting to run the minimal example below directly from the GitHub example file:
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <codecvt>

typedef struct _SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION {
    PVOID EntryPoint;
    ULONG StackZeroBits;
    ULONG StackReserved;
    ULONG StackCommit;
    ULONG ImageSubsystem;
    WORD SubSystemVersionLow;
    WORD SubSystemVersionHigh;
    ULONG Unknown1;
    ULONG ImageCharacteristics;
    ULONG ImageMachineType;
    ULONG Unknown2[3];
} SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION, * PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG Size;
    HANDLE Process;
    HANDLE Thread;
    CLIENT_ID ClientId;
    SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION ImageInformation;
} RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION, * PRTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION;

#define RTL_CLONE_PROCESS_FLAGS_CREATE_SUSPENDED    0x00000001
#define RTL_CLONE_PROCESS_FLAGS_INHERIT_HANDLES     0x00000002
#define RTL_CLONE_PROCESS_FLAGS_NO_SYNCHRONIZE      0x00000004

#define RTL_CLONE_PARENT                0
#define RTL_CLONE_CHILD                 297

typedef DWORD pid_t;

typedef NTSTATUS(*RtlCloneUserProcess_f)(ULONG ProcessFlags,
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ProcessSecurityDescriptor /* optional */,
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ThreadSecurityDescriptor /* optional */,
    HANDLE DebugPort /* optional */,
    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation);


int fork()
{
    DWORD parent_pid = GetCurrentProcessId();

    HMODULE mod;
    RtlCloneUserProcess_f clone_p;
    RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;
    NTSTATUS result;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> stringConverter;
    mod = GetModuleHandle(stringConverter.from_bytes("ntdll.dll").data());
    if (!mod)
        return -ENOSYS;

    clone_p = (RtlCloneUserProcess_f)GetProcAddress(mod, "RtlCloneUserProcess");
    if (clone_p == NULL)
        return -ENOSYS;

    /* lets do this */
    result = clone_p(RTL_CLONE_PROCESS_FLAGS_CREATE_SUSPENDED | RTL_CLONE_PROCESS_FLAGS_INHERIT_HANDLES, NULL, NULL, NULL, &process_info);

    if (result == RTL_CLONE_PARENT)
    {
        HANDLE me = 0, hp = 0, ht = 0, hcp = 0;
        DWORD pi, ti, mi;
        me = GetCurrentProcess();
        pi = (DWORD)process_info.ClientId.UniqueProcess;
        ti = (DWORD)process_info.ClientId.UniqueThread;

        assert(hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pi));
        assert(ht = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ti));

        ResumeThread(ht);
        CloseHandle(ht);
        CloseHandle(hp);

        return (int)pi;
    }
    else if (result == RTL_CLONE_CHILD)
    {
        /* fix stdio */
        FreeConsole();
        AttachConsole(parent_pid);

        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;

    /* NOTREACHED */
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    switch (pid) {
    case 0: //child
    {
        printf("I am child.\n");
        break;
    }
    default: //parent
        printf("I am parent. Child process PID: %d\n", pid);
        break;
    }
    Sleep(1000);

    exit(0);
}

Results in only the parent process printing the output:
I am parent. Child process PID: 35484

It appears that any created child processes in this example don't return to execute after the fork() call, which is I'm assuming the expected behaviour here.

I'm also aware that threads can provide a simillar behaviour here, however what I'm looking for is to clone/fork an entirely new process that has it's own stack & heap memory.

I'm also aware that Cygwin has implementations of the ZwCreateProcess function, as mentioned in the following post, but I am looking for the Win32 way of accomplishing this, not neccessarly as close to the Unix fork() as possible. A lot of people also mentioned the fact that the Cygwin implementation is apparently quite slow.

What is the proper way to clone/fork a process in C++ on a Windows system?
Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

If you don't need a full copy of the current state of your program use std::thread/std::mutex/std::scoped_lock and friends.

Even on posix systems, fork needs to be called prior to any thread creation or resource acquisition. The starting code prior to forking needs to be extremely simple.

This second example doesn't check for errors.

My first look would be at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/process.html -- they generally try to keep things fairly portable. Also, if fork just doesn't work, I would redesign things -- there's rarely a need for an actual full copy of the parent process.

There isn't one right way, and all the others are wrong, or anything like that. Proceeding from easy (but limited utility) to hard (but much more capable):
system. Allows you to specify a process to run. Runs independently, but that's about it. Just starts it up, and from there the child runs entirely on its own.
WinExec Pretty much like system, but harder to use.
ShellExecute. Somewhat like system, but adds the ability to "execute" a data file, about like if you double clicked the data file in an Explorer window. Starts the associated application, and opens that file in the application.
_popen/popen. Starts a child process, and returns a FILE *. When you call it, you specify whether you want to read the child process' output, or write to its input (but unfortunately, you can't choose both).
ShellExecuteEx is kind of tied with popen. Maybe a little harder to use, but not much. Like ShellExecute, can open data files as well as executables. Also gives you a handle to the child process, so you can wait for the child to finish executing, if you want to do that (none of the preceding support that, though if you use popen to read the child's output, reading until the end of its output is usually pretty close to the same).
CreateProcess. The main Win32-native way to start a process. Provides all the capabilities of the other methods, and more besides, so if (for example) you want to provide input to the child, and read output from the child and wait for the child to finish executing, you can do that. But doing all that is non-trivial. For example, years ago I wrote some code to start a child process, redirecting its input and output file handles to pipes and/or files of your choosing. Most of that is dealing with the files/pipes correctly (e.g., making handles inheritable, so the child be able to use them), but it's a total of something like 350 lines of code. Could probably be squeezed down quite a bit, but it's probably never going to be the half dozen lines you might wish for.
In case you'd like to look at that, here's some code:
// spawn.h
#ifndef SPAWN_H_INCLUDED_
#define SPAWN_H_INCLUDED_

// What to do if you ask to create a file and it already exists.
// We can fail to create it, overwrite the existing content, or append the
// new content to the existing content.
enum { FAIL, OVERWRITE, APPEND };

// This just specifies the type of a thread procedure to use to handle a stream
// to/from the child, if you decided to do that.
//
typedef unsigned long (__stdcall *ThrdProc)(void *);

// stream_info is the real core of the code. It's what lets you specify how
// to deal with a particular stream. When you call CreateDetchedProcess, 
// you need to pass the address of an array of three stream_info objects
// that specify the handling for the child's standard input, standard
// output, and standard error streams respectively. If you specify a
// filename, that stream will be connected to the named file. If you set
// filename to NULL, you can instead specify a procedure that will be
// started in a thread that will provide data for that stream, or process
// the data coming from that stream. In the demo program (see below) are
// a couple of sample handlers, one that processes standard error, and the
// other that processes standard output from a spawned child process.
//
typedef struct {
    char *filename;
    ThrdProc handler;
    HANDLE handle;
} stream_info;

// Once you've filled in your stream_info structures, spawning the child is
// pretty easy: just pass the name of the executable for the child, and the
// address of the stream_info array. This handles most of the usual things:
// if you don't specify an extension for the file, it'll search for it with
// extensions of `.com", ".exe", ".cmd", and ".bat" in the current
// directory, and then in any directory specified by the PATH environment
// variable. It'll open/create any files you've specified in the
// stream_info structures, and create pipes for any streams that are to be
// directed to the parent, and start up threads to run any stream handlers 
// specified.
// 
HANDLE CreateDetachedProcess(char const *name, stream_info *streams);

#endif

...and the implementation:
// spawn.c
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "spawn.h"

static void system_error(char const *name) {
// A function to retrieve, format, and print out a message from the
// last error.  The `name' that's passed should be in the form of a
// present tense noun (phrase) such as "opening file".
//
    char *ptr = NULL;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        0,
        GetLastError(),
        0,
        (char *)&ptr,
        1024,
        NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", ptr);
    LocalFree(ptr);
}

static void InitializeInheritableSA(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *sa) {

    sa->nLength = sizeof *sa;
    sa->bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa->lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
}


static HANDLE OpenInheritableFile(char const *name) {
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE retval;

    InitializeInheritableSA(&sa);

    retval = CreateFile(
        name,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);


    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == retval) {
        char buffer[100];

        sprintf(buffer, "opening file %s", name);

        system_error(buffer);
        return retval;
    }
}

static HANDLE CreateInheritableFile(char const *name, int mode) {
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE retval;

    DWORD FSmode = mode ? OPEN_ALWAYS : CREATE_NEW;

    InitializeInheritableSA(&sa);

    retval = CreateFile(
        name,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        &sa,
        FSmode,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == retval) {
        char buffer[100];

        sprintf(buffer, "creating file %s", name);

        system_error(buffer);
        return retval;
    }
    
    if ( mode == APPEND ) 
        SetFilePointer(retval, 0, 0, FILE_END);
}

enum inheritance { inherit_read = 1, inherit_write = 2 };

static BOOL CreateInheritablePipe(HANDLE *read, HANDLE *write, int inheritance) {

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    InitializeInheritableSA(&sa);

    if ( !CreatePipe(read, write, &sa, 0)) {
        system_error("Creating pipe");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!inheritance & inherit_read)
        DuplicateHandle(
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            *read,
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            NULL,
            0,
            FALSE,
            DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    if (!inheritance & inherit_write) 
        DuplicateHandle(
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            *write,
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            NULL,
            0,
            FALSE,
            DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    return TRUE;
}

static BOOL find_image(char const *name, char *buffer) {
// Try to find an image file named by the user.
// First search for the exact file name in the current
// directory.  If that's found, look for same base name
// with ".com", ".exe" and ".bat" appended, in that order.
// If we can't find it in the current directory, repeat
// the entire process on directories specified in the
// PATH environment variable.
//
#define elements(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

    static char *extensions[] = {".com", ".exe", ".bat", ".cmd"};
    int i;
    char temp[FILENAME_MAX];

    if (-1 != access(name, 0)) {
        strcpy(buffer, name);
        return TRUE;
    }

    for (i=0; i<elements(extensions); i++) {
        strcpy(temp, name);
        strcat(temp, extensions[i]);
        if ( -1 != access(temp, 0)) {
            strcpy(buffer, temp);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    _searchenv(name, "PATH", buffer);
    if ( buffer[0] != '\0')
        return TRUE;

    for ( i=0; i<elements(extensions); i++) {
        strcpy(temp, name);
        strcat(temp, extensions[i]);
        _searchenv(temp, "PATH", buffer);
        if ( buffer[0] != '\0')
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}


static HANDLE DetachProcess(char const *name, HANDLE const *streams) {
    STARTUPINFO s;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p;
    char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof s);
    s.cb = sizeof(s);
    s.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    s.hStdInput = streams[0];
    s.hStdOutput = streams[1];
    s.hStdError = streams[2];

    if ( !find_image(name, buffer)) {
        system_error("Finding Image file");
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

// Since we've redirected the standard input, output and error handles
// of the child process, we create it without a console of its own.
// (That's the `DETACHED_PROCESS' part of the call.)  Other
// possibilities include passing 0 so the child inherits our console,
// or passing CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE so the child gets a console of its
// own.
//
    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL,
        buffer, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE,
        DETACHED_PROCESS,
        NULL, NULL,
        &s,
        &p))
    {
        system_error("Spawning program");
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

// Since we don't need the handle to the child's thread, close it to
// save some resources.
    CloseHandle(p.hThread);

    return p.hProcess;
}

static HANDLE StartStreamHandler(ThrdProc proc, HANDLE stream) {

    DWORD ignore;

    return CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        proc,
        (void *)stream,
        0,
        &ignore);
}

HANDLE CreateDetachedProcess(char const *name, stream_info *streams) {
// This Creates a detached process.
// First parameter: name of process to start.
// Second parameter: names of files to redirect the standard input, output and error 
//  streams of the child to (in that order.)  Any file name that is NULL will be 
//  redirected to an anonymous pipe connected to the parent.
// Third Parameter: handles of the anonymous pipe(s) for the standard input, output
// and/or error streams of the new child process.
//
// Return value: a handle to the newly created process.
//

    HANDLE child_handles[3];
    HANDLE process;

    int i;

// First handle the child's standard input.  This is separate from the 
// standard output and standard error because it's going the opposite 
// direction.  Basically, we create either a handle to a file the child
// will use, or else a pipe so the child can communicate with us.
// 
    if ( streams[0].filename != NULL ) {
        streams[0].handle = NULL;
        child_handles[0] = OpenInheritableFile(streams[0].filename);
    }
    else
        CreateInheritablePipe(child_handles, &(streams[0].handle), inherit_read);

// Now handle the child's standard output and standard error streams.  These
// are separate from the code above simply because they go in the opposite 
// direction.
//
    for ( i=1; i<3; i++) 
        if ( streams[i].filename != NULL) {
            streams[i].handle = NULL;
            child_handles[i] = CreateInheritableFile(streams[i].filename, APPEND);
        }
        else 
            CreateInheritablePipe(&(streams[i].handle), child_handles+i, inherit_write);

// Now that we've set up the pipes and/or files the child's going to use,
// we're ready to actually start up the child process:
    process = DetachProcess(name, child_handles);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == process)
        return process;

// Now that we've started the child, we close our handles to its ends of the pipes.
// If one or more of these happens to a handle to a file instead, it doesn't really 
// need to be closed, but it doesn't hurt either.  However, with the child's standard
// output and standard error streams, it's CRUCIAL to close our handles if either is a
// handle to a pipe.  The system detects the end of data on a pipe when ALL handles to
// the write end of the pipe are closed -- if we still have an open handle to the
// write end of one of these pipes, we won't be able to detect when the child is done
// writing to the pipe.
//
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++) {
        CloseHandle(child_handles[i]);
        if ( streams[i].handler ) 
            streams[i].handle = 
                StartStreamHandler(streams[i].handler, streams[i].handle);
    }
    return process;
}

...and a little demo program to show how to use that:
#include "spawn.h"

#define buf_size 256

unsigned long __stdcall handle_error(void *pipe) {
// The control (and only) function for a thread handling the standard
// error from the child process.  We'll handle it by displaying a
// message box each time we receive data on the standard error stream.
//
    char buffer[buf_size];
    HANDLE child_error_rd = (HANDLE)pipe;
    unsigned bytes;

    while (ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE != GetLastError() &&
        ReadFile(child_error_rd, buffer, 256, &bytes, NULL))
    {
        buffer[bytes+1] = '\0';
        MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Error", MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long __stdcall handle_output(void *pipe) {
// A similar thread function to handle standard output from the child
// process.  Nothing special is done with the output - it's simply
// displayed in our console.  However, just for fun it opens a C high-
// level FILE * for the handle, and uses fgets to read it.  As
// expected, fgets detects the broken pipe as the end of the file.
//
    char buffer[buf_size];
    int handle;
    FILE *file;

    handle = _open_osfhandle((long)pipe, _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY);
    file = _fdopen(handle, "r");

    if ( NULL == file )
        return 1;

    while ( fgets(buffer, buf_size, file))
        printf("%s", buffer);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    stream_info streams[3];
    HANDLE handles[3];
    int i;

    if ( argc < 3 ) {
        fputs("Usage: spawn prog datafile"
            "\nwhich will spawn `prog' with its standard input set to"
            "\nread from `datafile'.  Then `prog's standard output"
            "\nwill be captured and printed.  If `prog' writes to its"
            "\nstandard error, that output will be displayed in a"
            "\nMessageBox.\n",
                stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(streams, 0, sizeof(streams));

    streams[0].filename = argv[2];
    streams[1].handler = handle_output;
    streams[2].handler = handle_error;

    handles[0] = CreateDetachedProcess(argv[1], streams);
    handles[1] = streams[1].handle;
    handles[2] = streams[2].handle;

    WaitForMultipleObjects(3, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
        CloseHandle(handles[i]);

    return 0;
}

Disclaimer: this is old C code. If I were writing new code to do the same thing today, I'd do a number of things differently.

However, what I'm looking for here is being able to clone a process and have it resume executing within the function I cloned it in, which is not what these CreateProcess functions do.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for here, but essentially all of these will allow the parent process to continue executing while the child process executes

thanks for sharing this, it's quite interesting. If I'm understanding this correctly, this also needs an executable file path to be provided to the child process in order to run, correct?

@Runsva: Yes and no. It does need at least the name of an executable. But if that executable is in a directory specified in the PATH environment variable, it can find it on its own (using the included find_image function).

To clarify what I meant in the snippet you referenced in your edit; I was looking for a way of having any created child process start executing from the point at which they were cloned in the code, AKA right after the call to the cloning function. But it does appear, the more I look at all this, that something like that is indeed impossible to do on Windows, and only available with the Unix fork() or it's Cygwin implementation (which I do not wish to use here). It seems like I'll just have to get my implementation to work by creating a new process with another executable file.

And just to clarify, in your example, you are expecting the provided executable file to simply read contents of a file, and output them using the standard output, right? I see that you are reading stuff from a pipe connected to the program launched with the child created child process.

@Runsva: oh,now I understand--yeah, doing an equivalent of fork on Windows is ugly.

@Runsva: As far as the example goes: I'm expecting the child to read its input from standard input and write its output to standard output (and possibly standard error).
